# Program to replace word in string using C

Tags: c, string

Ive been working on a c program that will allow the user to type in line of text until they type in the phrase "The end" on a line by itself. The program will replace every occurrence of "is" with the string "was" and count the number of changes made.

so far I've written some code but I'm getting a little lost on how to get it to work correctly, as of right now the program is giving me a buffer overflow error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main ()
{
    char str[500];// ="- This, a sample string.";
    char * pch;
    char endTerm[5000];

    printf("Enter a string to parse: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",str);
    strcat(endTerm, str);


    while ( (strcmp(str, "the end")) != 0 || (strcmp(str, "the end.")) != 0 )
    {
            scanf("%[^\n]",str);
             strcat(endTerm, str);
    }



    printf ("Your original string was: %s\n\n",endTerm);
    pch = strtok (endTerm," ,-");


    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        if ((strcmp(pch, "is")) == 0)
        {
            pch = "was";
        }
        else if ((strcmp(pch, "is.")) == 0)
        {
            pch="was.";
        }


        printf ("%s ",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,-");
    }

    printf("\n\n");





    return 0;
}
```

I can probably figure out how to end the program if the user types the end, but i really need help with replacing the word is with was.

Comment: Your code produces a very large number of compiler warnings. You should fix all of those before asking for help on here, since they are certainly the source of the issues you're having.

Comment: I just checked Xcode again and removed lines of code that Xcode is warning me about

Comment: Still too many basic errors. For example: `strcat(finalString, strcat(" ",pch) );` where do you think `finalString` points to? It's never set so trying to write to it is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: `(strcmp(pch, "is")) == true` Did you read the [`strcmp` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)? Does it really tell you that `strcmp` returns `true`?

Comment: u should only call strtok with userString the first time you call it, subsequent times you should call it with NULL as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments above, there are several flaws in your program.

1. First flaw is your usage of `strcat` function. If you read the documentation, you would understand that `strcat` treats the first argument as a destination pointer and hence expects the user to allocate sufficient memory (enough to hold the concatenated string) to the destination pointer. In your case you are passing a string of " " which can accommodate only 1 character. This is the reason, you are getting the buffer overflow or segmentation fault.
2. The second error in your program is in the usage of `strcmp` function. This function returns 0 (which is defined by `false` and not `true` in `strbool.h`) when two strings are equal.
3. The third problem in your program is in the usage of the function `strtok`. You need to pass NULL as the first argument from the second call onward to get the pointers to the remaining tokens.

So fix these 3 errors first and then try to think about what else needs to be corrected in order to get your desired output.

Comment: I edited the code. I removed the #include <strbool.h>, I also got strtok to work correctly. the only problem I'm having is when i use             strcat(endTerm, str);    i get an overflow like before, I attempted to allocate 5000 characters to it but I get an overflow. Im not sure where to go from here, Im new to programming in c so im not used to using pointers.